# Passing PowerShell object to Function - Why does this not work

Tags: function, powershell, object, parameters

Why doesn't the below code print the object values when passed into a function? what am I missing?

```
$Name=@{}
$Name.firstName="John"
$Name.lastName="Doe"

$NameObj=new-object psobject -property $Name


function GetName([PSObject]$NameObj) {
    $NameObj
}

GetName
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to *pass* the value to the `GetName` function:

```
GetName $NameObj
```

Comment: It is so embarrassing, it missed my eye.

Comment: The name of the function is actually fine and does not need to be corrected. There are [PowerShell Style Guides](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/blob/master/Style-Guide/Function-Structure.md) that recommend using the Verb-Object naming for advanced functions and camel cases for simple functions like the one above.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching I didn't know that, thanks for mentioning and providing the link. I removed that comment.